# Memory Error when Iteratively Applying FSRCNN Model for Image Enhancement

Tags: image-processing, out-of-memory

I am currently working with the FSRCNN model to enhance image quality. Initially, when applying the model to a new image, the process works seamlessly. However, upon attempting to use the model iteratively on the output image from the first cycle, I encounter a memory error.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this memory error issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Error:** cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 6881280000 bytes in function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'

I tried to use the code on G-colab to encounter memory error but faced same error.